# Set value to input dynamically in ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to set variable name to input value so the data test selector value is same when value is entered in input box. if i currently use `value=item.name`

it displays the name in input box. i juzt want value to be set as variable name when value in input entered it is also assigned to data-test-selector. like old code as shown below.

Trying to use dynamically using each

```
{{#each items as |item|}}
        <input id={{item.name}} maxlength="15" class="form-control" data-test-License={{item.name}} {{action "myAction" onEvent="keyUp"}} value=item.name/>
{{/each}}
```

old code

```
{{input type="text" maxlength="15" class="form-control" value=product data-test-selector=product}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forgot to wrap `item.name` with `{{`.
2. there is no `onEvent`. but there is `on` like `on="keyUp"` refer guide section [Specifying the Type of Event](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/templates/actions/#toc_specifying-the-type-of-event)
3. myAction method should update the value to `item.name` property or you could try the below.

   `<input id={{item.name}} maxlength="15" class="form-control" data-test-License={{item.name}} value={{item.name}} oninput={{action (mut item.name) value="target.value"}}>`

---

Update:
**can we add observer or action event where we allow user to only enter numeric and no alphabets?**
You dont need to use observer in this case, `oninput={{action 'updateName' item}}`

```
updateName(item, event){
  let number = event.target.value.toString().replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
  Ember.set(item,'name',number);
}
```

Comment: can we add observer or action event where we allow user to only enter numeric and no alphabets

Comment: you can say `type="number"` which will allow only numbers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: This will add updown arrows for number i would want to use action or observer

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: if i add value={{item.name}}it displays the variable name we are trying to set in input box and not empty box also when i add 'updateName' item inside action it gives error  as "Assertion Failed: Cannot call get with 'target.value' on an undefined object.",

Comment: did you figure it out? if not update the code you tried in question or better in [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) link

Comment: in data-test-License={{item.name}} i want the "data-test-License" name to be set dynamically on each

Comment: That will set automatically. I created this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b6a6932486033f59a365c9f12dda11ab?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) for you. I would recommend you to provide non working twiddle so that I can fix whats wrong.

Comment: The twiddle u have given display's name inside the input box we don't want {{item.name}} to be displayed inside input box. Also test selectors should be unique like for eg. 1st input box it shouldhave  data-test-john and 2nd input box it should be data-test-doe and the value of these selector should display the input entered in input box

Comment: I am having hard time to understand your use case. anyhow as far as my understanding you are saying you want to sync text filed value to `item.name` but initially it should be empty..if thats the case you can make it item.name value to empty initially.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157486/discussion-between-user2583182-and-kumkanillam).